# Arbitrary large unsigned integers

Tags: c, integer

**Edit**: There's now a [Follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164914/fup-arbitrary-large-unsigned-integers) concerning more recent code.

---

From time to time, you see a question over at Stack Overflow about calculating factorials, typically asking why the result soon gets completely wrong when increasing the input number. The typical answers explain how types are limited, how you could approximate a factorial, how you could use a big number library like `gmp`, and so on. And you will stumble over a well-meant advice *not to roll your own bignum implementation*.

Challenge accepted ;) So the following code is just for training, and, admittedly, for fun, and although I'm quite experienced, it was a learning experience as well. I'm putting the result for review because I might have missed some bugs, some unnecessary inefficiencies, or even might have broken portability in a subtle way, and if so, it would be great if someone could spot this.

When I started implementing it, I had the following goals in mind:

- Handle *any* size of an unsigned integer, no compile-time limits
- Do this in portable code
- Provide a reasonable "intuitive" interface on an opaque type
- Try to achieve good performance

Functions for converting to and from a string are needed and because the naive implementations (using a lot of multiplications and divisions by `10`) proved to be horrible bottlenecks, I replaced them with implementations based on the [Double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) algorithm.

**hugeint.h**

```
#ifndef HUGEINT_H
#define HUGEINT_H

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct hugeint hugeint;

hugeint *hugeint_create(void);
hugeint *hugeint_clone(const hugeint *self);
hugeint *hugeint_fromUint(unsigned int val);
hugeint *hugeint_parse(const char *str);

hugeint *hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands,
        unsigned int *residue);
hugeint *hugeint_ladd(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands);
hugeint *hugeint_vadd(size_t n, va_list ap);
hugeint *hugeint_add(size_t n, ...);
hugeint *hugeint_2comp(const hugeint *self);
hugeint *hugeint_sub(const hugeint *self, const hugeint *diff);
hugeint *hugeint_shiftleft(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *positions);
hugeint *hugeint_shiftright(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *positions);
hugeint *hugeint_mult(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *factor);
hugeint *hugeint_div(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *divisor,
        hugeint **mod);

int hugeint_isZero(const hugeint *self);
int hugeint_compare(const hugeint *self, const hugeint *other);
int hugeint_compareUint(const hugeint *self, unsigned int other);

void hugeint_increment(hugeint **self);
void hugeint_decrement(hugeint **self);

char *hugeint_toString(const hugeint *self);

#endif
```

**hugeint.c**

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hugeint.h"

#define HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int))

// start each new "hugeint" with 256 bits:
#define HUGEINT_INITIAL_ELEMENTS (256 / HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS)

struct hugeint
{
    size_t n;
    unsigned int e[];
};

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *m = malloc(size);
    if (!m) exit(1);
    return m;
}

static void *xrealloc(void *m, size_t size)
{
    void *m2 = realloc(m, size);
    if (!m2) exit(1);
    return m2;
}

static size_t copyNum(char **out, const char *str)
{
    const char *p = str;
    const char *start;
    size_t length = 0;
    while (*p && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t' || *p == '0')) ++p;
    if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') return 0;

    start = p;
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
    {
        ++p;
        ++length;
    }

    *out = xmalloc(length + 1);
    (*out)[length] = 0;
    memcpy(*out, start, length);
    return length;
}

static hugeint *hugeint_expand(hugeint *self)
{
    hugeint *expanded = xrealloc(self,
            sizeof(hugeint) + 2 * self->n * sizeof(unsigned int));
    memset(&(expanded->e[expanded->n]), 0, expanded->n * sizeof(unsigned int));
    expanded->n *= 2;
    return expanded;
}

hugeint *hugeint_create(void)
{
    hugeint *self = xmalloc(sizeof(hugeint)
            + HUGEINT_INITIAL_ELEMENTS * sizeof(unsigned int));
    memset(self, 0, sizeof(hugeint)
            + HUGEINT_INITIAL_ELEMENTS * sizeof(unsigned int));
    self->n = HUGEINT_INITIAL_ELEMENTS;
    return self;
}

hugeint *hugeint_clone(const hugeint *self)
{
    hugeint *clone = xmalloc(sizeof(hugeint) + self->n * sizeof(unsigned int));
    memcpy(clone, self, sizeof(hugeint) + self->n * sizeof(unsigned int));
    return clone;
}

hugeint *hugeint_fromUint(unsigned int val)
{
    hugeint *self = hugeint_create();
    self->e[0] = val;
    return self;
}

hugeint *hugeint_parse(const char *str)
{
    char *buf;
    hugeint *result = hugeint_create();
    size_t bcdsize = copyNum(&buf, str);
    if (!bcdsize) return result;

    size_t scanstart = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t i;
    unsigned int mask = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < bcdsize; ++i) buf[i] -= '0';

    while (scanstart < bcdsize)
    {
        if (buf[bcdsize - 1] & 1) result->e[n] |= mask;
        mask <<= 1;
        if (!mask)
        {
            mask = 1;
            if (++n == result->n) result = hugeint_expand(result);
        }
        for (i = bcdsize - 1; i > scanstart; --i)
        {
            buf[i] >>= 1;
            if (buf[i-1] & 1) buf[i] |= 8;
        }
        buf[scanstart] >>= 1;
        while (scanstart < bcdsize && !buf[scanstart]) ++scanstart;
        for (i = scanstart; i < bcdsize; ++i)
        {
            if (buf[i] > 7) buf[i] -= 3;
        }
    }

    free(buf);
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands,
        unsigned int *residue)
{
    hugeint *result = hugeint_create();

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        while (summands[i]->n > result->n)
        {
            result = hugeint_expand(result);
        }
    }

    unsigned int res = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < result->n; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int bit = 1; bit; bit <<= 1)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if (i >= summands[j]->n) continue;
                if (summands[j]->e[i] & bit) ++res;
            }
            if (res & 1) result->e[i] |= bit;
            res >>= 1;
        }
    }

    if (residue) *residue = res;
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_ladd(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands)
{
    unsigned int res;
    hugeint *result = hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow(n, summands, &res);

    if (res)
    {
        size_t i = result->n;
        result = hugeint_expand(result);
        result->e[i] = res;
    }

    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_vadd(size_t n, va_list ap)
{
    const hugeint **summands = xmalloc(n * sizeof(hugeint *));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        summands[i] = va_arg(ap, hugeint *);
    }

    hugeint *result = hugeint_ladd(n, summands);

    free(summands);

    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_add(size_t n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    hugeint *result = hugeint_vadd(n, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_2comp(const hugeint *self)
{
    hugeint *tmp = hugeint_clone(self);
    if (hugeint_isZero(tmp)) return tmp;
    hugeint *one = hugeint_fromUint(1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp->n; ++i)
    {
        tmp->e[i] = ~(tmp->e[i]);
    }
    hugeint *result = hugeint_add(2, tmp, one);
    free(tmp);
    free(one);
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_sub(const hugeint *self, const hugeint *diff)
{
    if (diff->n > self->n) return 0;
    int freediff = 0;
    if (diff->n < self->n)
    {
        freediff = 1;
        diff = hugeint_clone(diff);
        while (diff->n < self->n) diff = hugeint_expand((hugeint *)diff);
    }
    hugeint *tmp = hugeint_2comp(diff);
    if (freediff) free((hugeint *)diff);

    unsigned int res;
    hugeint *result = hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow(2,
            (const hugeint *const []){self, tmp}, &res);
    free(tmp);
    if (res > 1)
    {
        free(result);
        return 0;
    }
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_shiftleft(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *positions)
{
    hugeint *result = hugeint_clone(hi);
    hugeint *count;
    if (positions)
    {
        if (hugeint_isZero(positions)) return result;
        count = hugeint_clone(positions);
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    unsigned int highbit = 1U << (HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS - 1);
    do
    {
        if (result->e[result->n - 1] & highbit)
        {
            result = hugeint_expand(result);
        }
        int incelement = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < result->n; ++i)
        {
            int overflow = !!(result->e[i] & highbit);
            result->e[i] <<= 1;
            if (incelement) ++result->e[i];
            incelement = overflow;
        }
        if (count) hugeint_decrement(&count);
    } while (count && !hugeint_isZero(count));
    free(count);
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_shiftright(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *positions)
{
    hugeint *result = hugeint_clone(hi);
    hugeint *count;
    if (positions)
    {
        if (hugeint_isZero(positions)) return result;
        count = hugeint_clone(positions);
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    unsigned int highbit = 1U << (HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS - 1);
    do
    {
        int incelement = 0;
        size_t i = result->n;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            --i;
            int overflow = result->e[i] & 1;
            result->e[i] >>= 1;
            if (incelement) result->e[i] += highbit;
            incelement = overflow;
        }
        if (count) hugeint_decrement(&count);
    } while (count && !hugeint_isZero(count));
    free(count);
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_mult(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *factor)
{
    hugeint **summands=xmalloc(factor->n * HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS * sizeof(hugeint *));
    size_t n = 0;
    hugeint *bitnum = hugeint_create();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < factor->n; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int bit = 1; bit; bit <<= 1)
        {
            if (factor->e[i] & bit)
            {
                hugeint *summand = hugeint_shiftleft(hi, bitnum);
                summands[n++] = summand;
            }
            hugeint_increment(&bitnum);
        }
    }

    free(bitnum);
    hugeint *result = hugeint_ladd(n, (const hugeint **)summands);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) free(summands[j]);
    free(summands);
    return result;
}

hugeint *hugeint_div(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *divisor,
        hugeint **mod)
{
    if (hugeint_isZero(divisor)) return 0;

    hugeint *scaled_divisor = hugeint_clone(divisor);
    hugeint *remain = hugeint_clone(hi);
    hugeint *result = hugeint_create();
    hugeint *multiple = hugeint_fromUint(1);

    while (hugeint_compare(scaled_divisor, hi) < 0)
    {
        hugeint *tmp = hugeint_shiftleft(scaled_divisor, 0);
        free(scaled_divisor);
        scaled_divisor = tmp;
        tmp = hugeint_shiftleft(multiple, 0);
        free(multiple);
        multiple = tmp;
    }

    do
    {
        if (hugeint_compare(remain, scaled_divisor) >= 0)
        {
            hugeint *tmp = hugeint_sub(remain, scaled_divisor);
            free(remain);
            remain = tmp;
            tmp = hugeint_add(2, result, multiple);
            free(result);
            result = tmp;
        }
        hugeint *tmp = hugeint_shiftright(scaled_divisor, 0);
        free(scaled_divisor);
        scaled_divisor = tmp;
        tmp = hugeint_shiftright(multiple, 0);
        free(multiple);
        multiple = tmp;
    } while (!hugeint_isZero(multiple));

    if (mod) *mod = remain;
    else free(remain);
    free(multiple);
    free(scaled_divisor);
    return result;
}

int hugeint_isZero(const hugeint *self)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < self->n; ++i)
    {
        if (self->e[i]) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int hugeint_compare(const hugeint *self, const hugeint *other)
{
    size_t n;
    if (self->n > other->n)
    {
        for (size_t i = other->n; i < self->n; ++i)
        {
            if (self->e[i]) return 1;
        }
        n = other->n;
    }
    else if (self->n < other->n)
    {
        for (size_t i = self->n; i < other->n; ++i)
        {
            if (other->e[i]) return -1;
        }
        n = self->n;
    }
    else n = self->n;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        --n;
        if (self->e[n] > other->e[n]) return 1;
        if (self->e[n] < other->e[n]) return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int hugeint_compareUint(const hugeint *self, unsigned int other)
{
    for (size_t i = self->n - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (self->e[i]) return 1;
    }
    if (self->e[0] > other) return 1;
    if (self->e[0] < other) return -1;
    return 0;
}

void hugeint_increment(hugeint **self)
{
    int carry = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (*self)->n; ++i)
    {
        carry = !++(*self)->e[i];
        if (!carry) break;
    }
    if (carry)
    {
        size_t n = (*self)->n;
        *self = hugeint_expand(*self);
        if (*self) (*self)->e[n] = 1;
    }
}

void hugeint_decrement(hugeint **self)
{
    if (hugeint_isZero(*self)) return;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (*self)->n; ++i)
    {
        if ((*self)->e[i]--) break;
    }
}

char *hugeint_toString(const hugeint *self)
{
    if (hugeint_isZero(self))
    {
        char *zero = malloc(2);
        zero[0] = '0';
        zero[1] = 0;
        return zero;
    }

    size_t nbits = HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS * self->n;
    size_t bcdsize = nbits/3;
    size_t scanstart = bcdsize - 2;
    char *buf = xmalloc(bcdsize + 1);
    memset(buf, 0, bcdsize + 1);

    size_t i, j;

    i = self->n;
    while(i--)
    {
        unsigned int mask = 1U << (HUGEINT_ELEMENT_BITS - 1);
        while (mask)
        {
            int bit = !!(self->e[i] & mask);
            for (j = scanstart; j < bcdsize; ++j)
            {
                if (buf[j] > 4) buf[j] += 3;
            }
            if (buf[scanstart] > 7) scanstart -= 1;
            for (j = scanstart; j < bcdsize - 1; ++j)
            {
                buf[j] <<= 1;
                buf[j] &= 0xf;
                buf[j] |= (buf[j+1] > 7);
            }
            buf[bcdsize-1] <<= 1;
            buf[bcdsize-1] &= 0xf;
            buf[bcdsize-1] |= bit;
            mask >>= 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < bcdsize - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (buf[i]) break;
    }

    bcdsize -= i;
    memmove(buf, buf + i, bcdsize + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < bcdsize; ++i) buf[i] += '0';
    buf = xrealloc(buf, bcdsize + 1);
    return buf;
}
```

Example 1: **divide.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hugeint.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [dividend] [divisor]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    hugeint *dividend = hugeint_parse(argv[1]);
    hugeint *divisor = hugeint_parse(argv[2]);
    hugeint *remain;
    hugeint *result = hugeint_div(dividend, divisor, &remain);
    free(divisor);
    free(dividend);
    if (!result)
    {
        fputs("Error: division unsuccessful.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    char *resultstr = hugeint_toString(result);
    free(result);
    char *remainstr = hugeint_toString(remain);
    free(remain);
    puts(resultstr);
    free(resultstr);
    fputs("remainder: ", stdout);
    puts(remainstr);
    free(remainstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Example 2: **factorial.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hugeint.h"

hugeint *factorial(hugeint *self)
{
    hugeint *result = hugeint_fromUint(1);
    hugeint *factor = hugeint_clone(self);

    while (hugeint_compareUint(factor, 1) > 0)
    {
        hugeint *tmp = hugeint_mult(result, factor);
        free(result);
        result = tmp;
        hugeint_decrement(&factor);
    }
    free(factor);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [number]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    hugeint *number = hugeint_parse(argv[1]);
    hugeint *result = factorial(number);
    free(number);
    char *factstr = hugeint_toString(result);
    free(result);
    puts(factstr);
    free(factstr);
    return 0;
}
```

The code as presented in the question can be [browsed on github](https://github.com/Zirias/hugeint/tree/3cd95d11998c0112d61b75c1fb76871482ad9d9b).

The [current HEAD](https://github.com/Zirias/hugeint) contains improvements mostly based on suggestions/criticism from the answers.

Comment: Note that allocating 0 bytes and receiving a `NULL` pointer does not indicate out-of-memory.   `if (!m) exit(1);` --> `if (!m && size) exit(1);`  This concern may not be possible with OP's code though.

Comment: @chux, yes, I consider an attempt to allocate "nothing" a bug in this code, it's designed so this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like fairly *clean* code, but I see plenty of places it could be improved. Letting my eyes skim over it and stop on the weird bits...

```
hugeint *hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands,
        unsigned int *residue);
hugeint *hugeint_ladd(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands);
hugeint *hugeint_vadd(size_t n, va_list ap);
hugeint *hugeint_add(size_t n, ...);
```

This is weird. You have a sane-looking `sub` function, and a sane-looking `mult` function —

```
hugeint *hugeint_sub(const hugeint *self, const hugeint *diff);
hugeint *hugeint_mult(const hugeint *hi, const hugeint *factor);
```

— yet somehow when it comes to the simplest possible operation, `add`, you have all these weird helper functions and no way to just add two numbers? I'm looking for

```
hugeint *hugeint_add(const hugeint *a, const hugeint *b);
```

---

Having to write that function signature made me notice that your `sub` function's parameters are named `self` and `diff`, which makes no sense to me. `self` is a name usually reserved for the "this pointer" in OO style, so from the signature of this function I'd be expecting the equivalent of

```
auto hugeint_sub(auto self, auto diff) {
    self -= diff;
    return self;
}
```

But that's not what the function does — nor what I'd expected it to do *before* looking at the parameter names. So basically, your parameter names are misleading. The English names for them would be `minuend` and `subtrahend`, but personally I'd go with `a` and `b`. I think everyone knows what `sub(a, b)` means. :)

---

So let's look at that weird N-argument `add` function. Does it work?

```
hugeint *hugeint_ladd(size_t n, const hugeint *const *summands)
{
    unsigned int res;
    hugeint *result = hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow(n, summands, &res);

    if (res)
    {
        size_t i = result->n;
        result = hugeint_expand(result);
        result->e[i] = res;
    }

    return result;
}
```

We can tell instantly that it can't possibly work, because it's got this thing called `residue` that's basically a "carry flag" for the addition. The reason we know it can't be right is that this carry flag *doesn't have enough bits* to store an arbitrarily large number of carries!  Try adding together 4294967297 copies of the hugeint `4294967295` and see what happens. One bit of carry is only enough for 2 addends, and 32 bits of carry is only enough for 4294967296 addends. What you need is a `hugeint`'s worth of carry; or else just get rid of this whole "carry" business and just expand the result as you go; or else get rid of the notion that it's a good idea to add *arbitrarily many* addends and just make a `hugeint_add(a, b)` that does the obvious thing.

---

Speaking of trouble with carries, let's look at the shift-left and shift-right functions. They're interesting because you're using `hugeint` for the shift count itself, which is unlike any programming language or instruction set I'm aware of. The shift count can only sanely get as high as the *log* of the left-hand operand, which is to say, it had better fit into `size_t`. But okay, let's look at right-shift and find the place where you do "If the right-hand operand is bigger than 4 billion, just set the result to `0` and return"...

```
    if (count) hugeint_decrement(&count);
} while (count && !hugeint_isZero(count));
```

...Oh dear. You should definitely give this one a rewrite. At *minimum*, it should know that bit-shifting by a multiple of 8 is equivalent to a single `memmove`, and bit-shifting by any other number can be reduced to a `memmove` plus 1–7 loop iterations.

---

Speaking of bit-widths, why are you using `unsigned int` as your unit data type instead of `uint64_t` or `__uint128_t`? I guarantee that `uint64_t` would be faster for most of what you're doing.

---

The other confusing thing about that right-shift code is:

```
if (positions) {
    if (hugeint_isZero(positions)) return result;
    count = hugeint_clone(positions);
} else {
    count = 0;
}
```

Here we're assigning `0` (an `int`) to `count` (a `hugeint`). This isn't going to do what we wanted! ...Or rather, it is, but only via a very bizarre path. Here `0` means `NULL`, which because of the `if (count)` elsewhere in the function, means "do only 1 iteration". So this `0` semantically means `1`!

The ultimate effect of all this spaghetti code is to make it so that if the user accidentally passes in a null pointer —

```
hugeint *result = hugeint_shiftright(a, NULL);
```

— then his operand will be shifted by 1. If this behavior is desirable, it should be provided as a separate function:

```
hugeint *result = hugeint_shiftright_by_one(a);
```

Providing two separate functions for the two separate functionalities is not only good for the reader's sanity, it's also going to be more efficient, because you won't have all those `if`s confusing the CPU's branch predictor.

---

Getting back to `add`, I see this `hugeint_expand` function that you're calling all over the place. It *doubles* the length of the underlying array, which is way overkill. What you should be doing is computing the correct length for the array and then allocating exactly that much: that is, not

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while (summands[i]->n > result->n) {
        result = hugeint_expand(result);
    }
}
```

but rather

```
int result_n = result->n;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    result_n = max(result_n, summands[i]->n);
}
result = hugeint_expand(result, result_n);
```

That is, `hugeint_expand` needs to take a parameter that tells it the size of the array you want. Compare this API to [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) in C++; it should look very very similar.

---

There's definitely more to critique, but this should give you some ideas, anyway.

Comment: _self is a name usually reserved for the "this pointer"_ --> Anything in C specified that supports this?

Comment: You spotted an inconsistent change in design. The original idea was to have objects with mutator methods, `self` and the expand logic are leftovers from this. So thanks for bringing it to my attention! Also good catch about "add", i'll change this as well, and probably make the non-expanding version "private" (`static`) exclusively for subtracting.

Comment: I addressed some of your remarks [here](https://github.com/Zirias/hugeint/tree/master/src), but now I have a question regarding the base type: I started using `uintmax_t` and later changed it to `unsigned int` under the assumption that calculations in the *natural word size* of the platform should perform best. So why would a fixed size (`uint64_t`) perform better? Isn't this possibly implemented in software in the compiler runtime on some platforms, so the software aritmetics would "cascade"?

Comment: You can't "guarantee that `uint64_t` would be faster" than `unsigned int`, as implementations are permitted where they are the same type....

Comment: @chux: It's a keyword in Objective-C (and Objective-C++), Smalltalk, maybe some others. For its use in C code, you'd have to google around; I don't have any links on hand. (It's a pretty hard term to google for! Maybe just start with "C object-oriented programming" and see if you get some hits right away.)

Comment: "changed it to unsigned int under the assumption that calculations in the *natural word size* of the platform should perform best" — Sadly, `int` is no longer the "natural word size" of any platform you're likely to have access to. As certainly as death and taxes, you're programming on a 64-bit machine, and your compiler's `int` is 32-bit. (Some people program on 24-bit DSPs or 16-bit microcontrollers; some people don't pay taxes. ;))

Comment: Mutator methods would probably be faster in general than your current approach of allocating memory for every math operation. Take a look at how C++ does it — basically, you could provide a mutating `operator+=` as the base implementation, and then implement non-mutating `operator+` as a two-liner: `c = clone(a); c += b; return c`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Billions of processors in 2017 are 32- bit, 16 bit and 100s millions are 8 bit native integer size.  That majority is found in embedded devices like the dozen or so in your car.  C is very popular there so the majority of current platforms use 32/16 bit `int`, not  64-bit.  Although OP is likely using a 64-bit processor.

Comment: @chux: Everything you said is 100% technically correct.  I'm merely skipping most of the verbiage for the OP's benefit. If he's programming for DSPs or microcontrollers, he'll know it.  It's like the old gambler's proverb — if you look around the room and can't spot the person running a 64-bit CPU, it's you. ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone although I was experimenting targeting `win32` where `unsigned int` should indeed be the *natural word size* -- you're actually right. compiling my code now on `linux64`, I'm wasting the 64bit arithmetics that would be available. This is sad ... Can you suggest a way how to chose the "optimal" base type for any platform, from 8bit AVR or 6502 to 64bit ARM or x86 ...? I already fear this might be impossible ...

Comment: @Quuxplusone and of course you're right about the mutators. I guess I switched to an immutable design because that's "better" on a higher abstraction level (inherently thread-safe etc.). But the combination of both approaches seems to be a good way, and as I don't have operator overloading in C, I'll just have to think about good names. I now started with all *mutating* methods taking a `hugeint **` instead of just a `hugeint *`. This makes the intention to mutate explicit, and it allows to scale the size if necessary.

Comment: Re choosing the optimal base type for arithmetic: I have no idea; it would make a good question for StackOverflow. Something to watch out for as well is that some widening operations aren't available portably or even at all; e.g. C provides portable 8x8=16 multiplication and plausible 32x32=64 multiplication (with 64-bit `long long`) but no 64x64=128 multiplication at all. So the "right" type for arithmetic depends on what kind of arithmetic you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

- Multiplication cries for optimization (e.g. [Karatzuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or [Toom-Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication))
- Division also can be optimized; given a fast multiplication a most straightforward approach is [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Fast_division_methods).
- The semantics of `hugeint_sub` and `hugeint_decrement` is questionable, or, if I may say so, surprising.
- `hugeint_ladd_cutoverflow` assumes that the carry fits in an `unsigned int`. It is not necessarily a case.
- I don't think it is a good idea to interpret a `position` being `NULL` as an implicit *shift by 1*.

Comment: Thanks, your links made me curious enough to invest some more time in this toy project. I now have a multiplication method roughly using *karatsuba*, which made better shift, add and sub routines necessary. Still it's not a *huge* performance boost with the example naively calculating factorials, but I guess that's because the naive factorial algorithm very often multiplies a huge number with a small one ...